# Which file format for encryption on mobile devices

Tags: xml, json, encryption, yaml, protocol-buffers

i need a secure (AES Encrypted) File, which is the fastes for parse, the smallest footprint and easy to work with.

What can you suggest? XML, JSON, YAML or Google Protocol Buffers maybe?

Comment: Encryption is orthogonal to the choice of serializer.

Comment: It's much more relevant which platform you're using. On .net/mono protobuf-net is pretty good, but it requires more configuration/annotation than other formats.

Comment: i use qt/c++ and iOs, android

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, the short codes used by protobuf don't come from nowhere, but (see [image here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/some-internals-of-protobuf-net.html)) the upshot is it is damn quick, even on light frameworks

Comment: @MarcGravell thats impressive! I can write the protobuf Stream in any file i want and then encrypt it, or? And on Android protobuf outperform all others, since it's from google with nice support. But is protobuf working on iOS too? Not found good answers so far, only problems :(

Comment: @slopsucker the first depends entirely on what encryption APIs are available. Personally, I would hope to use a "decorator" style encrypting/decrypting stream, but I don't know what is available for C++/android. I know protobuf-net will work with Mono on android, but that isn't quite your preferred target, it seems. There are other protobuf implementations - indeed you could try the Google-owned c++ core implementation.

Comment: @MarcGravell im normally develop under C# .NET and really like it, much more than c++. But for this program, I must be so good as to cover all platforms... i think i'm develop with the botan lib for c++ and write a windows phone and metro app with c# and the new crypto lib from microsoft, since the old is then deprecated... and for XP, Vista and W7 Qt works well so long. But really Thanks for your Blog and this Post! Im getting to work with Protobuf.

Comment: @slopsucker Xamarin (Mono tools for iOs and 'droid) covers iPhone and android; VS covers WP7, XP, Vista, W7, W8, Metro... Just saying :) but obviously - whatever you decide is fine too

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, but there is *nix, mac and symbian/meegoo and blackberry missing. And Qt/C++ is for free and a bit faster than .NET (but not so convenient). I dont think that everything from .NET is working there.. especially encryption. But the Metro and Windows Phone App is the "sugar" of the Project. I'm already missing DataBinding and much little features like the @"path" .. :) I follow your Blog and hope getting protobuf net stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, XML/JSON etc are text based, which can make them *slightly* more expensive to parse (extra string work etc), and *certainly* larger (all those names in the payload). For both those reasons something like protobuf will certainly be useful if parse-cost and bandwidth are concerned. As for easy to work with: most platforms have a protobuf implementation. For deployment footprint: that would vary between platform and implementation - you'd have to check on your target platform, but: something built-in may be advantageous; as for what comes pre-installed as part of the mobile platform's SDK, that again depends on your target platform; I would expect XML for certain, JSON as likely.